# How do I end a child process after it is finished doing stuff?

Tags: c

Here is the code I'm using to create the n number of children and increment count:

```
int pid;
for(j = 1; j<=numForks; j++){
    if((pid=fork()) == 0){  /*child process*/
        count++;
    }else{ /*parent process*/

    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to exit out of each child. And I'm not allowed to use any sort of wait function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already assumed, just use [`exit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html)

```
int pid;
for(j = 1; j<=numForks; j++){
    if((pid=fork()) == 0){  /*child process*/
        count++;
        exit(0);
    }else{ /*parent process*/

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually doing something a bit more than just doing count++ in the child process. I'm doing `count =  findKey(in, key, buf, j, count);` and that function scans through a txt file and then returns the number of times it finds a certain string. Let's say count should be 1 after all the child processes. Inside the child process if I print out count after calling my findkey function, it prints out 1 (which is correct). Then if I do exit(0) after that, when I print  out count after my for loop, count is 0 again.

Comment: When you fork, everything (including count) is duplicated. After you exit a child, its count is gone. So, the count you see "after" the exit is the parent's count.

Comment: Which process printed count? Each process has its own copy of count (and all the other stuff too). If you want all of the processes to manipulate the same instance of count then it need to be mapped to all processes (for one method see mmap, and also you need to increment atomically)

Comment: Forgive me for I am very new to using forks. I'm assuming the main process printed count which from @OlafDietsche explanation explains why count is 0 still. How can I make it so that the value of count is retained then even after the process has ended? Do I uses pipe()? How do I use it?

Comment: @user2923535 You cannot keep the count value. When the process exits, it is gone. But you can use [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), but this another topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `kill` from the parent process or call `exit` from the child process or just let each child process terminate on it's own.